# Private variables in Perl Moose class

Tags: perl, moose

I am starting to learn about objects in Perl using Moose.

I am not sure if I understand the purpose of `MooseX::Privacy`. Consider:

```
use v5.14;

package PA {
    use Moose;
    my $var='private?';
    1;

    sub getVar {
        return $var;
    }
}

package PB {
    use Moose;
    use MooseX::Privacy;

    has 'var' => (
        is => 'rw',
        isa => 'Str',
        default   => 'private?',
        traits => [qw/Private/],
    );
    1;

    sub getVar {
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->var;
    }
}

my $o1= PA->new();
my $o2= PB->new();

say $o1->getVar();
say $o2->getVar();
```

In both class `PA` and `PB` I have a private variable `var`. Only in class `PB` I use `MooseX::Privacy`. What is the difference between these two approaches? And why should I use `MooseX::Privacy`?

Comment: No initialization from constructor arguments, no type checking, no coercion, no inheritance, no composing, no introspection, no ability to add traits, ...

Comment: PA's `$var` is static, PB's isn't. Besides that, is PA even using Moose in the first place? If you don't understand the advantages of Moose, the whole question is moot.

Comment: @ikegami I am only talking about private variables, so I would not use a constructor initialization on these anyway?

Comment: @rutter I did not include public variables in `PA` in order to make the example minimal..

Comment: Not sure. I don't have Moose handy to test. The list was more to give an idea than anything else. Your question is basically "What advantages does Moose provide?"

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for Java-style method privacy, then MooseX::Privacy is going to be a big disappointment. Here's what happens with Java style method privacy:

```
/* This file is called Main.java */
public class Main
{
    public class MyParent
    {
        private String message_string ()
        {
            return "Message from %s\n";
        }

        public void print_message ()
        {
            System.out.printf( this.message_string(), "MyParent" );
        }
    }

    public class MyChild extends MyParent
    {
        public String message_string ()
        {
            return "Another message from %s\n";
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Main o = new Main();
        o.run();
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        MyParent c = new MyChild();
        c.print_message();
    }
}
```

You can compile and run this example like this:

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
Message from MyParent
```

Note what's happened. The parent class (`MyParent`) declares `message_string()` to be a private method. The child class attempts to override the method but is roundly rebuffed - **no soup for you** child class!

Now let's try the equivalent with Perl and MooseX::Privacy...

```
# This file is called Main.pl
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyParent {
    use Moose;
    use MooseX::Privacy;

    private_method message_string => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return "Message from %s\n";
    };

    sub print_message {
        my $self = shift;
        printf($self->message_string(), __PACKAGE__);
    }
}

package MyChild {
    use Moose; extends qw(MyParent);
    use MooseX::Privacy;

    sub message_string {
        my $self = shift;
        return "Another message from %s\n";
    }
}

my $c = new MyChild();
$c->print_message();
```

We can run that like this:

```
$ perl Main.pl
Another message from MyParent
```

Say, **WHA?!?!?!** Ain't `message_string` supposed to be private?! How the hell did `MyChild` override the method in `MyParent`?!

The fact of the matter is, MooseX::Privacy doesn't give you anything close to method privacy as implemented in most OO languages. MooseX::Privacy is simply akin to doing this in your method:

```
die "GO AWAY!!" unless caller eq __PACKAGE__;
```

Except that MooseX::Privacy adds massive runtime expense to all your method calls.

Really, there's little reason to use MooseX::Privacy. If you want private methods, put them in lexical variables. Like this:

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyParent {
    use Moose;

    my $message_string = sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return "Message from %s\n";
    };

    sub print_message {
        my $self = shift;
        printf($self->$message_string(), __PACKAGE__);
    }
}

package MyChild {
    use Moose; extends qw(MyParent);

    sub message_string {
        my $self = shift;
        return "Another message from %s\n";
    }
}

my $c = new MyChild();
$c->print_message();
```

Now run it:

```
$ perl Main2.pl
Message from MyParent
```

**Hallelujah!!** We have a true private method!

OK, so you can have private methods without MooseX::Privacy, and they work better (and faster) than MooseX::Privacy.

But what about private attributes? Well, I have a little module on CPAN that can help you: [Lexical::Accessor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lexical%3a%3aAccessor). This is a little tool that creates an attribute for you, with "inside out" storage (i.e. the attribute value doesn't get stored in the object's blessed hashref), and installs the accessors for it in lexical variables (just like the private `$get_message` method above).

Anyway, that's my opinion on MooseX::Privacy.

Comment: Thanks for interesting answer! What would happen if the `print_message` method was defined in the child class instead of the parent? (Or if it was overridden in the child?)

Comment: If `print_message` is defined in `MyChild` then it can always call a `get_message` that is also defined in `MyChild` (no matter what privacy is chosen for `get_message`). If `print_message` is defined in `MyChild` but `get_message` is a private method defined in `MyParent`, then in Java (and using my lexical technique), it can't call `get_message` because it can't even see that `get_message` exists! With MooseX::Privacy, it can see it, and call it, but doing so will throw an exception.